# Converting Parse tree to Abstract Parse Tree

Tags: parsing, tree, abstract-syntax-tree

I have a parse tree that I wish to convert to an abstract parse tree.

[image]

I found found examples online but that are normally just simple addition.

I understand that I need to remove unnecessary information but I don't know how to lay it out with regards to the repeat and until.
Is this the correct APT for the concrete parse tree?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard which defines a "correct" AST. ASTs are used instead of parse trees only to make life easier for the application which is going to process the tree.

In short, the decision is entirely yours, and you should make it on the basis of what you intend to do with the AST.